# Are questions about the plugin directory welcome?

Tags: discussion, scope

Yesterday we closed [a question about the plugin directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2235/my-wordpress-plugin-is-no-longer-showing-up-in-the-wordpress-directory-closed), while last week [we answered one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/my-new-wordpress-plugin-version-is-not-showing-up-in-the-plugin-directory-its). John P Bloch commented *"If you have a problem with a WordPress.org plugin repository, I suggest you ask the people that run that website. They have plenty of outlets for such questions. This is simply the wrong place to ask that question."* I think one could use this logic to say WordPress Answers is not needed, since we already have [the WordPress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/).

Maybe we should take a step back and discuss whether we want these type of questions? I think they can be valuable, since they attract experts, and we need experts to keep this site alive.

Comment: *@Jan Fabry*: I actually think the question that was closed was on topic, so I'd really like understand the rationale for closing it.

Comment: @Mike: Indeed, I also think it was on topic, and I mentioned the earlier question because it was similar but not deleted. But maybe I should have been more specific: "Why did we close that question?"

Answer (score 3):

There was clear difference between those questions with one providing SVN details and other being generic *solve this for me*.

If it is possible to answer question about repository - I see no reason not to. I see no problem in how these two posts had been dealt with.

Otherwise such generalization can be made for any other topic, like writing queries. Asking for help with some aspect is fine, asking to write whole custom template specific to your blog is probably not so much.

Comment: Indeed, the latter question did not have much details (yet). But that could be corrected with a comment and a rewrite, whereas now the reason John gave was "there is enough support from WordPress.org, there is no need to ask it here." I don't agree with that vision.